# System.Web.Http methods missing in Nunit test project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-web-api2, .net-4.6.1, system.web.http

I am writing some unit test for an `ApiController`. I continue to get multiple `System.MissingMethodException` exceptions for methods in the `System.Web.Http` namespace.

> Message: System.MissingMethodException : Method not found: 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage System.Web.Http.ApiController.get_Request()'.
>
> Message: System.MissingMethodException : Method not found: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1 System.Web.Http.IHttpActionResult.ExecuteAsync(System.Threading.CancellationToken)'.

The test project compiles just fine, has the correct using statements, package references, and bindings. However, as soon as it tries to run, one of the above exceptions are thrown (whichever is first encountered, depending on how the code is structured). It may also be worth noting that when `System.Web.Http` methods are not used, the test project runs just fine.

I was hoping [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49447891/failure-to-include-system-web-http-in-unit-tests) had my answer, but I cannot find any discrepancies. I have uninstalled/reinstalled multiple times. Verified both projects use the same version (5.2.7.0). Verified that version is being used via viewing the Modules during debug. And verified that the reference path for both projects point to the correct nuget packages folder:(...\Main\src\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core.5.2.7\lib\net45\System.Web.Http.dll)

Below is the package and binding info, if anything else is needed please let me know. I've already wasted a couple days on this, any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Main Project - packages.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="AutoMapper" version="8.1.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.3" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="log4net" version="2.0.8" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.OData" version="7.1.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.2.7" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.7" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.2.7" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="5.2.7" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.OData.Core" version="7.5.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.OData.Edm" version="7.5.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Spatial" version="7.5.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="11.0.2" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="NLog" version="4.2.3" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Collections" version="4.0.11" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Collections.Concurrent" version="4.0.12" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.ComponentModel" version="4.0.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.Debug" version="4.0.11" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Globalization" version="4.0.11" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Linq" version="4.1.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Linq.Expressions" version="4.1.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Reflection" version="4.1.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Resources.ResourceManager" version="4.0.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" version="4.5.2" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.Extensions" version="4.1.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Threading" version="4.0.11" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Threading.Tasks" version="4.0.11" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Unity" version="5.10.1" targetFramework="net461" />
</packages>
```

**Main Project - web.config bindings**

```
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-11.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.7.0" newVersion="5.2.7.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.7.0" newVersion="5.2.7.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

**Test Project - packages.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="AutoMapper" version="8.1.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Castle.Core" version="4.3.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.3" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="log4net" version="2.0.8" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.OData" version="7.1.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.7" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.2.7" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.OData.Core" version="7.5.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.OData.Edm" version="7.5.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Spatial" version="7.5.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Moq" version="4.10.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="netDumbster" version="2.0.0.4" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="11.0.2" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="NUnit" version="2.6.4" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="NUnitTestAdapter" version="1.2" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Collections" version="4.0.11" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Collections.Concurrent" version="4.0.12" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.ComponentModel" version="4.0.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.Debug" version="4.0.11" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Globalization" version="4.0.11" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Linq" version="4.1.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Linq.Expressions" version="4.1.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Reflection" version="4.1.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Resources.ResourceManager" version="4.0.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" version="4.5.2" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.Extensions" version="4.1.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Threading" version="4.0.11" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Threading.Tasks" version="4.0.11" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions" version="4.5.1" targetFramework="net461" />
</packages>
```

**Test Project - app.config bindings**

```
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-11.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.7.0" newVersion="5.2.7.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.7.0" newVersion="5.2.7.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.4.1" newVersion="4.0.4.1" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

### Edit - adding project refs and modules screen shot

**Main Project - csproj references**

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="AutoMapper, Version=8.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=be96cd2c38ef1005, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\AutoMapper.8.1.0\lib\net461\AutoMapper.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="log4net, Version=2.0.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\log4net.2.0.8\lib\net45-full\log4net.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="EntityFramework.SqlServer, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\lib\net45\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.OData, Version=7.1.0.21120, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.OData.7.1.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.AspNet.OData.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.1.0.0\lib\netstandard1.1\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.1.0.0\lib\netstandard1.0\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.OData.Core, Version=7.5.0.20627, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.OData.Core.7.5.0\lib\portable-net45+win8+wpa81\Microsoft.OData.Core.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.OData.Edm, Version=7.5.0.20627, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.OData.Edm.7.5.0\lib\portable-net45+win8+wpa81\Microsoft.OData.Edm.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Spatial, Version=7.5.0.20627, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Spatial.7.5.0\lib\portable-net45+win8+wpa81\Microsoft.Spatial.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\WellsFargo.Azure.ChannelSecure.3.0.0.12\lib\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="NLog, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5120e14c03d0593c, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\WellsFargo.Azure.ChannelSecure.3.0.0.12\lib\NLog.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="SSORestIISModule, Version=3.0.0.9, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f8c74029db907226, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\WellsFargo.Azure.ChannelSecure.3.0.0.12\lib\SSORestIISModule.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="System.IO.Compression" />
    <Reference Include="System.Net" />
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=5.2.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client.5.2.7\lib\net45\System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.4.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.4.5.2\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Runtime.Serialization" />
    <Reference Include="System.ServiceModel" />
    <Reference Include="System.Transactions" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.DynamicData" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Entity" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.ApplicationServices" />
    <Reference Include="System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations" />
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Drawing" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Extensions" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core.5.2.7\lib\net45\System.Web.Http.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Http.WebHost, Version=5.2.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost.5.2.7\lib\net45\System.Web.Http.WebHost.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
    <Reference Include="System.Configuration" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Services" />
    <Reference Include="System.EnterpriseServices" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="Unity.Abstractions, Version=4.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=489b6accfaf20ef0, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Unity.5.10.1\lib\net46\Unity.Abstractions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Unity.Container, Version=5.10.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=489b6accfaf20ef0, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Unity.5.10.1\lib\net46\Unity.Container.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

**Test Project - csproj references**

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="AutoMapper, Version=8.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=be96cd2c38ef1005, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\AutoMapper.8.1.0\lib\net461\AutoMapper.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Castle.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=407dd0808d44fbdc, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Castle.Core.4.3.1\lib\net45\Castle.Core.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="EntityFramework.SqlServer, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\lib\net45\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="log4net, Version=2.0.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\log4net.2.0.8\lib\net45-full\log4net.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.OData, Version=7.1.0.21120, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.OData.7.1.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.AspNet.OData.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.1.0.0\lib\netstandard1.1\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.1.0.0\lib\netstandard1.0\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.OData.Core, Version=7.5.0.20627, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.OData.Core.7.5.0\lib\portable-net45+win8+wpa81\Microsoft.OData.Core.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.OData.Edm, Version=7.5.0.20627, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.OData.Edm.7.5.0\lib\portable-net45+win8+wpa81\Microsoft.OData.Edm.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Spatial, Version=7.5.0.20627, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Spatial.7.5.0\lib\portable-net45+win8+wpa81\Microsoft.Spatial.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Moq, Version=4.10.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=69f491c39445e920, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Moq.4.10.1\lib\net45\Moq.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="netDumbster, Version=2.0.0.4, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4a1d8c974aa1bd1c, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\netDumbster.2.0.0.4\lib\net461\netDumbster.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.11.0.2\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="nunit.core, Version=2.6.3.13283, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=96d09a1eb7f44a77, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\NUnitTestAdapter.1.2\lib\nunit.core.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="nunit.core.interfaces, Version=2.6.3.13283, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=96d09a1eb7f44a77, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\NUnitTestAdapter.1.2\lib\nunit.core.interfaces.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="nunit.framework, Version=2.6.4.14350, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=96d09a1eb7f44a77, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\NUnit.2.6.4\lib\nunit.framework.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="nunit.util, Version=2.6.3.13283, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=96d09a1eb7f44a77, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\NUnitTestAdapter.1.2\lib\nunit.util.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="NUnit.VisualStudio.TestAdapter, Version=1.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4cb40d35494691ac, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\NUnitTestAdapter.1.2\lib\NUnit.VisualStudio.TestAdapter.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations" />
    <Reference Include="System.Configuration" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=5.2.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client.5.2.7\lib\net45\System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.4.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.4.5.2\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.4.5.1\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core.5.2.7\lib\net45\System.Web.Http.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

**Screenshot of Modules window during debug, showing loaded assembly**
[image: Modules Window]

Comment: Which frameworks are the projects using? I had a similar problem and it turned out one was core and one was full framework.

Comment: @Squirrelkiller They are both using .net 4.6.1

Comment: The problem looks like: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47524409/11442461 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/46463872/11442461 as a problem in your web.config.

Comment: Any errors or warning in the output when building?

Comment: @Mario It does seem similar, but I have binding redirects in place on both projects (web/app configs above). However, if you do see something wrong with them, please let me know.

Comment: @Squirrelkiller Unfortunately, there are no errors or warnings from the build from either the error window or build output. I wish there were, as it would give me some direction.

Comment: Is it something personel zou can make open source? I could clone it and try to build and test myself.

Comment: No, it's an enterprise project. Thanks for the offer though.

Comment: Maybe, it would be helpful to get a look into parts of your project file (e.g., reference, post building tasks). I found no way to produce such a problem with a similar message. The dll-files are still available (only method not found) and should be in right version (wrong version generates another message). How do you run the failing unit test?
In such mysterious problems Sysinternals Process Monitor could be helpful. There you can check, which dll files are loaded, which configuration files are used. There could be a forgotten beta-version in your system.

Comment: @Mario I appreciate your continued effort on this. I don't have enough rights on my machine to install/access the process monitor utility, but I'll provide a screen shot of the loaded modules if that helps. Also, I'll add in the references of each project file for review. There are no pre/post build tasks. As far as running the tests go, I do this through the test explorer and either run tests individually or a set of tests. When running multiple tests, tests which do not reference the library run fine and pass. Test with a reference to the library fails before the method block is entered into

Comment: I run into similar problems with VS Test runner. With R# test runner it works fine! But, after I upgrade NUnit to actual version 3.1 and NUnitTestadapter to NUnit3Testadapter, it runs also with VS test runner. Can you upgrade the testproject for testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After working through several possibilities with the help of the people above. I decided to start from scratch, adding in each dependency until the error was recreated. I found that adding in the Moq library is where the issue begins. This seems to something specific to using Moq with .Net 4.6.1. You can read the details on their page [here](https://github.com/moq/moq4/issues/566).

The solution turned out to be quite simple though. Add the following to your test project's .csproj:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
  <GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>
</PropertyGroup>
```